# Initialise State as a class property or in constructor [ReactJS]

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've seen tow cases set default state like:

```
class Page extends Component {
  state = {
    page: 0,
  };
}
```

vs

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { page: 0 };
  }
}
```

Use first variant Is it bad practice? Where can i find out more information about it? Or how this ecmascript's feature is named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the first variant if you have `stage-2 preset` configured with babel. It is a class property syntax and is not event included in ES7 proposal, however it is available as stage-2 preset with babel. However using the first or the second variant is a matter of preference. They both transpile to the exact same thing.

**[First method:](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAKYHMCm0DeAoa0IBcw5QF41MtoAHRJALmgAYAaUgXwG51n0g&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false)**

**[Second method](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAKYHMCm0DeAoa1gHsB2EALgE4CuwhOxAFAJRqZbSEAWAlhAHRFiEoC8aaAAdESAFzQADNAC-Abkaz0yoA&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false)**

Comment: The links don't work