# react without constructor declaring state in class's body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I saw below code somewhere and I'm curious. It looks cleaned but unusual to me. Why `state = {}` is declared without an constructor?

and `load` declared without a function keyword? As I know for there are ways to write a function

`function async load() {}`
or
`const async load = ()=>{}`

And what `...args` does? is it spread `arguments`?

```
import View from './View';
import loadData from './loadData';
export default class extends Component {
  state = {};
  load = this.load.bind(this);
  async load(...args) {
    try {
      this.setState({ loading: true, error: false });
      const data = await loadData(...args);
      this.setState({ loading: false, data });
    } catch (ex) {
      this.setState({ loading: false, error: true });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View {...this.props} {...this.state} onLoad={this.load} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45832853/initialise-state-as-a-class-property-or-in-constructor-reactjs/45833026#45833026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state = {}` declaration is a class property, which is currently not part of the JavaScript language. Certain utilities such as Babel will compile this into legal JavaScript code.

However, the lack of a `function` keyword within classes, as well as the `...` operator are part of ECMAScript 6, which has been officially implemented into the language (though some browsers do not recognize it yet).

[Class Definition](http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition)
[Spread Operator](http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator)

Comment: that doesn't explain what the class instance variable definitions are

Comment: @AndyRay I did not realize, thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can initialize state without a constructor for a React class component:

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = { value: 0 };

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1
    }));
  };

  handleDecrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value - 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}

        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It uses **class field declarations** which are not part of the language yet but enabled with Babel. You can checkout a sample application over [here](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/react-alternative-class-component-syntax).

You can also use state in React function components (without a constructor), but using higher-order components or render prop components. You can find out more about it [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-without-constructor/).